# AJAX Call Returns Object in Chrome but Returns Null in Firefox and IE

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

My AJAX call works fine in Chrome but when I test it out in Firefox or IE, I receive a null response. Any help is much appreciated!

My PHP Function:

```
function get_ldap_attr() {

    $lan = $_POST['lan'];
    $dn = get_site_option ( "ldapServerOU" );
    $usr = get_site_option ( "ldapServerCN" );
    $pw = get_site_option ( "ldapServerPass" );
    $addr = get_site_option ( "ldapServerAddr" );
    $ad = ldap_connect ( $addr )
        or die ( "Connection error." );
    ldap_set_option ( $ad, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3 );
    ldap_set_option ( $ad, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0 );
    $bind = ldap_bind ( $ad, $usr, $pw );

    if ( $bind ) {
        $SearchFor ="cn=".$lan;
            $result = ldap_search ( $ad,$dn,$SearchFor );
            $entry = ldap_first_entry ( $ad, $result );
            if ( $entry != false )  {
                $info = ldap_get_attributes ( $ad, $entry );
            }           
            $comm  = stripos ( $info['manager'][0], ',' );
                // find position of first comma in CN=Mxxxxxx,OU=Users,OU=MCR,DC=mfad,DC=mfroot,DC=org  (directReports field)
            $eq = stripos ( $info['manager'][0], '=' );
                // find position of first =
            $s_lanid = substr ( $info['manager'][0], $eq+1, ( ( $comm-1 ) - ( $eq ) ) );
                //get substring between = and comma...
            $sup = getLDAPInfo ( $s_lanid, $bind, $ad, $dn ); 
                // get supervisor's info...
            $subInfo = getLDAPInfo ($lan, $bind, $ad, $dn);
    }
    echo json_encode( array( $sup, $subInfo ) );
    die();
}
```

My jQuery:

```
jQuery(function() {

    jQuery('#empLanId').on('blur', function() {
    var lan = jQuery('#empLanId').val(),
        data = { action: "get_ldap", lan: lan};
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: ajaxurl,
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {
                console.dir(response);

                jQuery('#empName').val(response[1].fullname);
                jQuery('#empSupLanId').val(response[0].lanid);
                jQuery('#empSupName').val(response[1].fullname);
                jQuery('#empSupNumber').val(response[1].phone);
            }

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Look at your network tab and see if there's any difference in the response between browsers.

Comment: What version of jQuery?

Comment: What's the print_r() for $sup in PHP?

Comment: You are sure that the URL and the data you use in the AJAX call are in all browsers the same?

Comment: print_r() returns the correct object. My company is running jQuery 1.7.1

Comment: All browsers the same? Can you elaborate?

Comment: You AJAX call has a `data` object with variables in it and also a `url` variable. You set them somewhere else in your code or in an input perhaps? What I mean is, are all those variables the same in IE, Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: You have a die(); - call ? Chrome maybe do not care, but FF and IE does?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld `die()` simply stops the PHP interpreter; browsers cannot detect whether or not it was used

Comment: There seems to be code missing.  Where is `get_ldap_attr()` called from?  Maybe something there is browser-sniffing?

Comment: @Izkata - I know what die() does :-)  But I can't figure out why die() even exists at the end of a function. Isn't that kind of pointless? Browser do treat warnings/errors differently. Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831555/jquery-ajax-and-php-die. I would at least try without the die()-call at the end of the function.

Comment: get_ladap_attr() is called from a WordPress plugin file.